# Socket Connection in iphone

Tags: iphone, sockets, connection

i m calling function "address = CFDataCreate(NULL, (uint8 *)&frameAddr, sizeof(frameAddr));" it runs fine 245 times but it cannot work after that gdb does not give any error

can anyone helps me????

Comment: You have provided too little information in your question for us to answer.  What does this have to do with a socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with sockets, the OS network stack will keep a closed socket around in a state (I think it's called FINWAIT) that has a timeout of a couple of minutes.  I think it's to handle the final ACK.

If you're making those 245 calls in fairly rapid succession perhaps you've reached an OS limit on number of connections due to all these connections waiting for clean up?

If gdb is not giving an error and the program seems to "hang" creating the sockets, that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: ok!!
i understand can you tell me what can i do for this prblem.
thanks in advance